# Go back to previous ViewController in xcode 5 storyboard

Tags: ios7, xcode5

**I am trying to create a back button on my iPhone app and I would like to go back to my landing view .. I am using this code but it did not work**

```
UIButton *back = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[back setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24)];
[back setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[back addTarget:self action:@selector(goback) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *btnBack = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:back];
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton= YES;
navEng.leftBarButtonItem = btnBack; 


-(void)goback{ [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this .... just changed last line code

```
UIButton *back = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; [back setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24)]; [back setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[back addTarget:self action:@selector(goback) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *btnBack = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:back];
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton= YES;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnBack;
```

```
-(void)goback
{
     [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**navEng** is declared as  `IBoutlet` `UINavigationItem` in header file and the back button appears and the action handled correctly but the navigation to the previous `ViewController` did not worked

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navEng;
UIButton *back = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [back setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24)];
    [back setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [back addTarget:self action:@selector(goback) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *btnBack = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:back];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton= YES;
    navEng.leftBarButtonItem = btnBack;



  -(void)goback{
       NSLog(@"back");
       [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```